# plotting a model based on data

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I want to plot a velocity versus depth model using the given data.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

depth=np.array((0.0,5.0,30.0,40.0,50.0))
velocity=np.array((5.5,6.5,6.8,9.0,10.0))
plt.plot(velocity,depth)
plt.show()
```

But this script doesnot give the plot as i expected
I need something like [example_plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExG3M.png)

I hope experts may help me overcoming this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Result]

You have to use [matplotlib.pyplot.step](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.step.html)

```
depth=np.array((0.0,5.0,30.0,40.0,50.0))*-1
velocity=np.array((5.5,6.5,6.8,9.0,10.0))
plt.step(velocity,depth)
plt.show()
```

EDIT:

```
depth=np.array((0.0,5.0,30.0,40.0,50.0))
velocity=np.array((5.5,6.5,6.8,9.0,10.0))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.step(velocity,depth)
ax.invert_yaxis()
fig.show()
```

[image: New picture without minus signs]

Comment: @imbuningbabe, Thanks. However I donot need minus sign on y axis , how can it be done??

Comment: I corrected the code, check now